# Google Repository isn't in the SDK manager

Tags: android, sdk

I'm working on an Android Studio project that will use the Google APIs. To do so I need to install the Google Repository from the SDK Manager, but it's not there. It has the Google Play services, and that's it. Any ideas on how to get the Google Repository package into the Extras directory of my SDK?

Comment: Make sure that you have upgraded to the latest SDK Tools, SDK Platform-tools, and SDK Build-tools in the Tools portion of the SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Makw sure to restart the SDK Manager after installing the latest SDK Tools, SDK Platform-tools, and SDK Build-tools in the Tools portion of the SDK Manager.